# Factor Analysis in Python and Stata

Tags: python, stata, factor-analysis

I have a dataset with 29 items to be run Exploratory Factor Analysis. I have implemented this dataset with the same factors in both Python and Stata, but I have two different results. Actually they are different since I identified the eigenvalues: in Python it is 4 but in Stata only 2.

Why are there  such differences and which result should I take?
Here are my codes
Python

```
df = df[df.g1 == 3]
fa = FactorAnalyzer()
fa.set_params(n_factors=6) # so factor
fa.fit(df)
fa.loadings_
fa_loading_df = pd.DataFrame(fa.loadings_, columns=['Factor 1', 'Factor 2', 'Factor 3', 'Factor 4', 'Factor 5', 'Factor 6'])
```

Stata

```
factor k2x1-k2x29 if g1==3, factor(6)
rotate, varimax norm blanks(.40)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Factor analysis isn't as standardised as you might imagine. For further details, I think you need to post a reproducible example with a  dataset and code in both programs.

Comment: I would put that in the question. As already edited, please note that the spelling is Stata, not STATA.  More importantly, you want someone who uses both Python and Stata to answer -- that's not me --  and without showing any data or results you may not get much help.

Comment: @NickCox thanks, I have edited the question. I am a newbie. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand what type of exploratory factor analysis (EFA) each command performs, and what type YOU want it to perform.
There are multiple types of EFA, such as principal factor, principal component factor, ML etc.

My guess Python and Stata have different default methods, hence you get different results. In your commands, you don't specify the method to be used, hence the default methods is used.

In Stata, the default is principal factor, while in Python, my guess is the default is minres, according to this web: https://factor-analyzer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/factor_analyzer.html

Comment: thank you very much. I have read the website you sent, I forgot using varimax (orthogonal rotation) as I performed in Stata, therefore no rotation has been performed!!! Do you have any explanation for the difference of eigenvalues?

Comment: I'm glad you found the explanation. The difference in factor loadings is due to rotation, as you mention. The difference in eigenvalues is most probably due to the factor calculation (command "factor" in Stata). You can specify the type of factor calculations you want:                                                
         factor k2x1-k2x29 if g1==3, factor(6) pcf                                                        
Stata offers several options: pf, pcf, ipf, ml - you need to make sure your factor calculation method is the same in Stata and Python in order to get the same eigenvalues.

Comment: So, in Python, you need to modify the option "method" to change eigenvalues: classfactor_analyzer.factor_analyzer.FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=3, rotation='promax', method='minres', use_smc=True, is_corr_matrix=False, bounds=(0.005, 1), impute='median', rotation_kwargs=None)

Comment: You can use method 'principal' in Python, which should correspond to 'pcf' method in Stata (or it could be 'pf', I'm not 100% sure on this one). Or use method 'ml' in Python which should correspond to 'ml' in Stata. I don't think Stata supports method 'minres'.

Comment: Your guidance is really helpful for the one who has not much background like me!! I can search documents based on your suggestions and I've found many useful things!!! I will read more!!! Sincerely thanks, from Diep